# JavaScript Proxy: How to Empty Array Target

Tags: javascript, proxy, watch

Consider the following JavaScript [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```
const queue = new Proxy([], {

    get: (target, property) => {
        return target[property];
    },

    set: (target, property, value) => {

        target[property] = value;

        this._processQueue();

        return true;

    }

});
```

The purpose of the above is to create a `queue` which is automatically processed whenever an item is added to it.

The problem is that once the `queue` is processed, I need to call `flushQueue` to remove the processed items. In other words, I need to empty the `queue` Proxy array.

Can anyone advise how to do this?

### What I have tried...

```
// Can't do this as a) queue is a constant, and b) it overrides the Proxy
queue = [];

// For some reason this doesn't work
queue.length = 0; 

// This empties the array but for some reason does not reset the length...
queue.splice(0, queue.length);
```

## Update

Please see my full example here:

```
class Foo {

    /**
     * Foo constructor.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    constructor() {

        this.queue = new Proxy([], {

            get: (target, property) => {
                return target[property];
            },

            set: (target, property, value) => {

                this._processQueue();

                target[property] = value;

                return true;

            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Add an event to the queue.
     *
     * @param {object} event
     * @return void
     */
    _addToQueue(event) {
        this.queue.push(event);
    }

    /**
     * Process the event queue.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    _processQueue() {

        console.log('process queue', this.queue, this.queue.length);

        if (this.queue.length) {

            this.queue.forEach((event, index) => {

                console.log(event);

                const method = this._resolveEvent(event.type);

                const payload = typeof event.payload !== 'undefined' ? event.payload : {};

                //this[method](payload);

            });

            this._flushQueue();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Flush the event queue.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    _flushQueue() {
        this.queue.splice(0, this.queue.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you set it to empty array again ? can you please create a minimum reproducible example ?

Comment: @CodeManiac - I have posted up my full code with irrelevant bits stripped out. If I run `this.queue = [];` then it will remove the `Proxy` and just be a normal array. Or am I wrong? It seemed to do that when I did it before....

Comment: Why you're calling `this._processQueue();` inside set trap, it seems to create a infinite loop

Comment: @CodeManiac the reason I am triggering the process method is the whole reason why I have set up the Proxy. Whenever a change is detected on the queue array, the queue should be processed. Essentially I am trying to create a watcher for the queue array and based on what I found online, this seems to be the way to do it. The reason there is an infinite loop is because `splice` does not seem to be resetting the length of the array when I remove the items, therefore `if (this.queue.length)` always evaluates to true once an item has been added. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, wasn't able to understand the motive behind using proxy before this comment, the problem is placement of `this._processQueue` you're calling it before setting the value, whereas you should call it after setting the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is you're calling `this._processQueue` before setting value to target, so it end-up in infinite loop, because it never set the value to target

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = new Proxy([], {
      get: (target, property) => {
        return target[property];
      },
      set: (target, property, value) => {
        console.log('set called', value)
        target[property] = value;
        this._processQueue();
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  _addToQueue(event) {
    this.queue.push(event);
  }

  _processQueue() {
    console.log('process queue', this.queue, this.queue.length);
    if (this.queue.length) {
      this.queue.forEach((event, index) => {
        console.log(event);
        //                 const method = this._resolveEvent(event.type);
        const payload = typeof event.payload !== 'undefined' ? event.payload : {};
        //this[method](payload);
      });
      this._flushQueue();
    }
  }

  _flushQueue() {
    this.queue.splice(0, this.queue.length);
  }
}

const q = new Foo()
q._addToQueue({
  type: 'clcik',
  payload: 'hello'
})
q._processQueue()
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You are absolutely right, I can't believe it was such a basic mistake! Thank you!!